# Drawing with Replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Say I have a bag of n marbles, red and blue, and every time I pull out a red marble I colour it blue and replace it.  What is P(# of trials until all blue marbles = k)?  What kind of distribution would this follow if draws are completely random?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In analogy with the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) the easy thing to calculate is the expected number of draws.  If you start with $r$ red marbles and $b$ blue ones, the expected time to color the first marble blue is $\frac {r+b}r$, the time to color the second one after coloring the first is $\frac {r+b}{r-1}$ and so on.  The expected time from start to color $k$ marbles is then $(r+b)(H_r-H_{r-k})$ where $H_i$ are the [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)

The distribution is much more difficult.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a good start.  What if I also supposed that we start with all red marbles?

Comment: Sorry, I had the wrong denominator.  All red is no problem-with $b=0$ you color one blue on the first draw.

Comment: Not a problem could you explain a bit more about how the harmonic numbers come into play?  And at a more basic level why $\frac {r+b}r$ works?  Is this also related at all to the voting problem in which catalan numbers are used?  I knew I had seen this problem somewhere before but I am not sure I understand.

Comment: Each time you draw, you have a chance of $\frac r{r+b}$ of getting a red ball.  This makes a geometric distribution of times to get the first red, with expected time the inverse of the chance of the red.  For the harmonic numbers, look at the articles I linked to.  They explain it well.  The difference of harmonic numbers comes if you stop before you paint all the red balls.

Answer (score 0):

Label the red balls $1,\ldots,r$.  For any fixed $k$, let $p_1$ be the probability that ball $1$ is not selected in these $k$ draws, $p_{1,2}$ the probability that neither ball $1$ nor ball $2$ is selected, and so on.  Using inclusion/exclusion, the probability that all red balls are selected within the first $k$ draws is
$$P_k=1-p_1-p_2-\cdots+p_{1,2}+\cdots-p_{1,2,3}-\cdots+(-1)^rp_{1,\ldots,r}\ .$$
But
$$p_1=p_2=\cdots=\Bigl(\frac{n-1}{n}\Bigr)^k$$
and
$$p_{1,2}=\cdots=\Bigl(\frac{n-2}{n}\Bigr)^k$$
and so on.  Therefore
$$P_k=\sum_{j=0}^r (-1)^j\Bigl({r\atop j}\Bigr)\Bigl(\frac{n-j}{n}\Bigr)^k$$
and the probability you want is $P_k-P_{k-1}$.